# Differential Cryptanalysis of FEAL-4

Tags: cryptanalysis, differential-analysis, feal

I'm currently carrying out a differential attack on the FEAL-4 algorithm, however I have hit a bit of a wall.

Basically I attacked the final round first ($K3$) using the differential characteristic of 0x80800000 which yields a differential of `0x02000000` with a probability of $1$.

I have found four possibilities for the round 4 subkey. To advance the attack to the next round (round 3) and verify which key is the correct one, I need to choose a new differential characteristic (other than `0x80800000`) to attack round 3.

I know the difference in the input to round 2 should be `0x02000000`, so I can begin my attack on round 3 — but how do I go about finding my differential characteristic so I can generate my plaintext/ciphertext pairs?

Comment: 'requests to decrypt data are off-topic' - maybe so, but that doesn't mean all cryptanalysis questions are off-topic! This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me

Comment: Closely related: [Differential cryptanalysis - breaking the last round of FEAL4?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/differential-cryptanalysis-breaking-the-last-round-of-feal4)